# Can't see Acrobat JS console when PDF is in an FF browser window

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, pdf

Windows 7 (64 bit), Acrobat Pro 9.4(32 bit), FF 3.6.11(32 bit)

In Firefox, I briefly see the JS console flash and then vanish... but it stays empty.

IE will show the JS console if it's already open, and displays a brief error message and then crashes Acrobat:  "Exception in line 18 of function top_level, script Page:Open".  I don't have a function `top_level`.  Acrobat isn't very good about telling you where an exception actually came from.  This is NOT in a browser window thanks to 64-bit IE vs 32-bit Acrobat.

PS: I have JS debugging turned on and I set it to break on a throw... changing it to "trace" stopped the IE crash, so that's something...  I even got the rest of the exception.  Turns out my install of IE wants to download the PDF, and the submit is to a relative URL... it has to do with 32-bit Acrobat vs 64-bit IE.  My hunting leads me to believe that there's no such thing as "64-bit Acrobat", and I haven't been able to convince my machine to install a 32-bit IE.  Wheee.

I'm not at all sure when this broke.  It could have been FF 3.6.11, or it could have been Acrobat 9.4.  IIRC, it was working relatively recently... but then I haven't done much PDF JS debugging lately, so it could have been a version or two prior on either side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has since started working again in Acrobat X.  Hurray.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of things I would try, though my experience with acrobat js console is minimal:

1. Try editing the pdf in Acrobat and hit "Ctrl + j" to open the console and debug from there
2. Use Firebug to debug.  You should be able to see everything acrobat is doing by sifting through the DOM tab, though that may be a bit tedious.  You should at least be able to see javascript errors in the console.

Comment: *My* experience withthe JS console in acrobat is quite a ways from minimal.   Firebug can only access script within firefox's DOM.  I'm afraid you'll have to do better than that.  :/